# how to apply condition on json response in NIFI

Tags: python, json, vue.js, vuetify.js, apache-nifi

[image]

```
{


"alamrs": [
{ 
  "correlate": [
    " ", 
    " ", 
    " " 
  ], 
"event": " ", 
  "group": " ", 
  "history": [
    {
      "event": " ", 
      "href": " ", 
      "id": " ", 
      "resource": " abc ", 
      "status": " ", 
      "text": " ", 
      "type": " ", 
      "updateTime": " ", 
      "user": " ", 
      "value": "--"
    }
  ],

  "href": " ", 
  "id": "", 
  "rawData": null, 
  "receiveTime": " ", 
  "service": [
    " "
  ], 
"resource": "abc", 
  "status": " ", 
  "tags": [
    ""
  ], 
"text": " : ", 
  "timeout": , 
}, 
{ 
"correlate": [
    " ", 
    " ", 
    " " 
  ], 
"event": " ", 
  "group": " ", 
  "history": [
    {
      "event": " ", 
      "href": " ", 
      "id": " ", 
      "resource": " abc ", 
      "status": " ", 
      "text": " ", 
      "type": " ", 
      "updateTime": " ", 
      "user": " ", 
      "value": "--"
    }
  ],

  "href": " ", 
  "id": "", 
  "rawData": null, 
  "receiveTime": " ", 
  "service": [
    " "
  ],
"resource": "abc", 
  "status": " ", 
  "tags": [
    ""
  ], 
"text": " : ", 
  "timeout": , 
}, 
{ 
  "correlate": [
    " ", 
    " ", 
    " " 
  ], 
"event": " ", 
  "group": " ", 
  "history": [
    {
      "event": " ", 
      "href": " ", 
      "id": " ", 
      "resource": " abc ", 
      "status": " ", 
      "text": " ", 
      "type": " ", 
      "updateTime": " ", 
      "user": " ", 
      "value": "--"
    }
  ],
"href": " ", 
  "id": "", 
  "rawData": null, 
  "receiveTime": " ", 
  "service": [
    " "
  ], 
"resource": "abc", 
  "status": " ", 
  "tags": [
    ""
  ], 
  "text": " : ", 
  "timeout": , 
}
```

[here i have used http invoked processor which get alarm from web app ....the response of this processor is in json format ...actually i want this alarm get filter on the bases of resource =abc ..i meant to say the alarm that have the resource = abc which are store in text file ][routedonatrribute configration--property_name=condtion value=${alamrs.resource:equals('abc')}][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGUtw.png)[evalutejsonpath---(property=destination- value=flowfile-attribute) (propety_name=condition value=$.alamrs.resource)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGUtw.png)[complete data flow][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGUtw.png)`[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0pCF.png`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [`PartitionRecord`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.11.4/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PartitionRecord/index.html) with a `JsonPathReader` to send all records in the flowfile with [`/*[./alarms/resource=abc]`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html) to one relationship and the others to a different relationship.